# Gostaria de saber qual a função do s [i] == s [f] no código

Tags: python

Estou estudando e me deparei com esse código, gostaria de saber pra que serve s[i] == s[f]

```
s = input("Digite o número a verificar, sem espaços:")
i = 0
f = len(s)-1  # posição do último caracter da string
while f > i and s[i] == s[f]:
    f = f - 1
    i = i + 1
if s[i] == s[f]:
    print(f"{s} é palíndromo")
else:
    print(f"{s} não é palíndromo")
```

Comment: Esse código está errado então pouco importa. Fora que pede para digitar um número, oque se fosse pra fazer isso ele seria capicua e não palíndromo.

Comment: Aparentemente na primeira comparação o primeiro caractere da string retornada com o ultimo, veja o resultado: https://ideone.com/6HY7hR, depois compara os próximos, mas em resumo as [...] é para obter o caractere especifico.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que a entrada seja o valor `123454321`, você terá:

```
Posição      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
s        =   1  2  3  4  5  4  3  2  1
             ↑                       ↑
             i                       f
```

O seu laço de repetição determina que enquanto `f` for maior do que `i` e que o caractere na posição `i` seja o mesmo que da posição `f` o valor de `f` decrementará em 1 enquanto o valor de `i` incrementará em 1.

Primeira iteração:

```
Posição      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
s        =   1  2  3  4  5  4  3  2  1
                ↑                 ↑
                i                 f
```

Segunda iteração:

```
Posição      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
s        =   1  2  3  4  5  4  3  2  1
                   ↑           ↑
                   i           f
```

Assim em diante, até que uma das condições seja falsa: ou `f` é menor ou igual a `i` ou os caracteres em ambas as posições são diferentes.